# Not getting an ID in Sails.js on compose.io

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I'm creating a blog post and the auto-created ID never makes it to my MongoDB database on compose.io

Here is the json result of my beforeCreate function (just for testing)

```
{ free: true,
  published: true,
  title: 'Ojfwneof',
  slug: 'ojfwneof',
  post: 'njwornijerbn',
  id: null }
```

Here is the json result from my create function in my BlogController:

```
{ free: true,
  published: true,
  title: 'hiurwgier',
  slug: 'hiurwgier',
  post: 'bfjirwbfejkrf',
  id: '55887edba5bb4113e4173edd',
  createdAt: Mon Jun 22 2015 16:32:11 GMT-0500 (CDT),
  updatedAt: Mon Jun 22 2015 16:32:11 GMT-0500 (CDT) }
```

And here is the json data store inside my compose.io database (note the null value on id):

```
{
  free: true,
  published: true,
  title: "fnjrwnk",
  slug: "fnjrwnk",
  post: "fnjkrwnjoewrn",
  id: null,
  createdAt: ISODate("2015-06-22T21:26:43.049Z"),
  updatedAt: ISODate("2015-06-22T21:26:43.049Z"),
  _id: ObjectId("55887d9308cdfe8de3ae78e6")
}
```

Here is my Blog model:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        free: {
            type: 'boolean',
            required: true,
            defaultsTo: false
        },

        published: {
            type: 'boolean',
            required: true,
            defaultsTo: false
        },

        title: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        slug: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        post: {
            type: 'text',
            required: true
        }

    },

    beforeCreate: function(val, next) {
        console.log(val);
        next();
    }
};
```

And here is my create function in my BlogController:

```
create: function(req, res) {
        Blog.create(req.params.all(), function newPost (err, post) {
            if(err) res.badRequest();
            console.log(post);
            res.json(post);
        });
    },
```

Comment: I don't see the `id` attribute defined in your model. Have you tried setting `schema:false`?

Comment: Thanks for your response @JuanSolano. It is set to `schema: false` and the id attribute should automatically get added via Waterline docs https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#collection.

Comment: I've reached out to compose.io to see if there is any type of settings I'm missing on their end. I have multiple Mongo databases on their platform and have never had this issue though. That's why I'm stumped on it.

Comment: Ok so what about the `_id` attribute, that is the default naming convention of Mongo. That is the one you should be using. I thought your `id` was some internal thing you were doing but if it is the KP your are looking for then `_id` is the one.